# Shell and sed: adding an array element to a PHP file

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have a php file:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule'
    ),
);
```

Since I'm lazy, I'm writing a script that will add an element to 'modules' array with a simple call:

```
$ sh myscript.sh 'NewModule'
```

NewModule should be added after the last 'modules' element.

I tried doing this with 'sed' command but I didnt succeed yet. Any help is welcome.

Comment: It seems like you're expending extra effort to implement something that's more likely to break.  If you're lazy, wouldn't it be less work to have your shell script simply write an extra line to a text file, then slurp that text file into the array using [`file()`](http://php.net/file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed '/modules..=>.array/,/),/ { /[^(,]$/ s//&,\n        '\''NewModule'\''/ }' file.php
```

Results:

```
<?php
 return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'NewModule'
    ),
);
```

You can make the regex more strict if you'd like. But I'll leave that job up to you.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in comments, I think an easier way would be to read the new data using [`file()`](http://php.net/file), which turns things into an array already.

```
<?php

$thing=array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule'
    )
);

foreach(file("modules.txt") as $new) {
  $thing['modules'][]=trim($new);
}

print_r($thing);
```

And the results:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat modules.txt
foo
bar
[ghoti@pc ~]$ echo "snerkle" >> modules.txt 
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -f myphpfile.php 
Array
(
    [modules] => Array
        (
            [0] => Application
            [1] => DoctrineModule
            [2] => DoctrineORMModule
            [3] => foo
            [4] => bar
            [5] => snerkle
        )

)
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

The only reason to use `foreach(){}` is to let you `trim()` each element.  If you don't mind the elements of `['modules']` having newlines on the end, you can simply replace the loop with:

```
$thing['modules']=array_merge($thing['modules'], file("modules.txt"));
```

I'm not sure what your `return` was about.  Perhaps the code in your question was an excerpt from a function.  Anyway, this should be enough to get the idea across.